# How to change topic name in function call?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, python2.7, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to run the same code on different robots, and they have different tf prefixes.
So instead of making n files, I want to just change the prefix in the function, here called ns

```
def movebase_client(ns, x, y):

    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('ns/move_base', MoveBaseAction)
    client.wait_for_server()
```

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391025/how-to-change-topic-name-in-function-call?/) by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-11-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-16**:
You could pass ns as a string and concatenate /move_base

**Comment by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on 2021-11-16**:
Yes, that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made it work doing this

```
def movebase_client(ns, x, y):

    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient(ns + '/move_base', MoveBaseAction)
    client.wait_for_server()
```

and then when you call the function,

```
movebase_client('Bot1', 4.0, 4.0)
```

This, however, does not allow me to change the values in the launch file. For this, I had to use the param server.
In the python file, I wrote this:

```
x = rospy.get_param('~x_position')
y = rospy.get_param('~y_position')

client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction)
client.wait_for_server()
```

and then in the launch file I could then change the values doing this:

```
  <node pkg="okg" name="name" type="name.py" output="screen">
      <remap from="move_base"       to="Bot1/move_base"/>
      <param name="~x_position"      type="double"      value="2.0"/>
      <param name="~y_position"      type="double"      value="2.0"/>
  </node>
```

Thanks, osilva and Geoff.

---

Originally posted by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) with karma: 170 on 2021-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-16**:
Great. You can accept your answer now by clicking on the checkmark button.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but the usual way to handle this sort of problem in ROS is to use [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) of topics. You can also place an entire collection of nodes/topics in a namespace by putting them in a [group](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group) in your launch file and setting the `ns` attribute of the group.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2